# Передать сгенерированный список в VM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Общая задача:  к списку имен добавить префиксы(суффиксы) состоящие из текста и номера по порядку (сформировать новый список имен = префикс + имя + суффикс).

На скриншоте пример (для краткости только с префиксом)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При вводе текста в Text и StartNumber (1 на скрине)  формируется список префиксов - для наглядности вывел в ListBox(2 скрине). Нужно чтобы в (3) было префикс + имя.
Код:

```
namespace WpfTestAddPrefix
{
    public class AppViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private InputTextNumber _inputPrefix;
        public InputTextNumber InputPrefix
        {
            get => _inputPrefix;
            set { _inputPrefix = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
        }
        //список для ItemsControl для вводимых данных: InputPrefix, InputSuffix
        public List<InputTextNumber> Inputs { get; }

        //список для получения из InputPrefix.ResultList 
        private BindingList<string> _prefixes;
        public BindingList<string> Prefixes
        {
            get => _prefixes; 
            set { _prefixes = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
        }

        private BindingList<BaseClassViewModel> _bases;
        public BindingList<BaseClassViewModel> Bases
        {
            get => _bases;
            set { _bases = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
        public AppViewModel() 
        {
            _bases = new BindingList<BaseClassViewModel>
            {
                new BaseClassViewModel(new BaseClass{Name = "Project aaa"}),
                new BaseClassViewModel(new BaseClass{Name = "Project bbbb"}),
                new BaseClassViewModel(new BaseClass{Name = "Project ddd"}),
                new BaseClassViewModel(new BaseClass{Name = "Project rrrr"}),
                new BaseClassViewModel(new BaseClass{Name = "Project yyyy"})
            };
            _inputPrefix = new InputTextNumber("Prefix",Bases.Count);
            Inputs = new List<InputTextNumber> { _inputPrefix };
            InputPrefix.ResultList.ListChanged += InputPrefixListChanged;

        }
        private void InputPrefixListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
            {
                Prefixes = InputPrefix.ResultList;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
    //класс для ввода текста и номера для генерации списка префикс
    public class InputTextNumber : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string _textPrefix;
        public string TextPrefix
        {
            get => _textPrefix;
            set 
            {
                _textPrefix = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged(); 
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ResultList)); 
            }
        }
        string _numberStart;
        public string NumberStart
        {
            get => _numberStart;
            set 
            { 
                _numberStart = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged(); 
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ResultList)); 
            }
        }
        public BindingList<string> ResultList 
        {
            get
            {
                BindingList<string> listRezult = new BindingList<string>();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(NumberStart))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < NumberAmount; i++)
                    {
                        listRezult.Add(TextPrefix);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    int startINT = Convert.ToInt32(NumberStart);

                    for (int i = startINT; i < startINT + NumberAmount; i++)
                    {
                    
                        listRezult.Add(TextPrefix + Convert.ToString(i));
                    }
                }
                return listRezult;
            } 
        }
        public string Name { get; }
        public int NumberAmount { get; }
        public InputTextNumber(string name, int numberAmount) 
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.NumberAmount = numberAmount;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }


}
```

базовые классы:

```
public class BaseClassViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BaseClass _baseClass;

    public BaseClassViewModel(BaseClass baseClass)
    {
        _baseClass = baseClass;
    }
    
    public string NameOld 
    {
        get { return _baseClass.Name; }
    }
    
    private string _nameNew;
    public string NameNew
    {
        get { return _nameNew; }
        set
        {
            _nameNew = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}
public class BaseClass
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return _name; } 
        set { _name = value; } }
}
```

не понимаю как передать сгенерированный список в VM. Может вообще сам подход неверный?
UPD:
т.е. из InputPrefix.ResultList в Prefixes
UPD2: добавил xaml

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" >
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Inputs}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="65"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            
                            <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14"
                                    Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,10,0"  >Text</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" TextAlignment="Center"  >NumStart</TextBlock>

                            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" TextAlignment="Right" 
                                    Text ="{Binding TextPrefix, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,2,0" 
                                    Text ="{Binding NumberStart, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <TextBlock>ResultList</TextBlock>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding InputPrefix.ResultList}"></ListBox>

        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Bases}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock  
                            Text="{Binding NameNew, 
                            Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        
    </Grid>
```

UPD3(для понимания того для чего нужен номер в префиксе и/или суффиксе):
например из программы выгружены файлы в пдф, но имена файлов должны быть как в примере ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понял, перечитал кучу раз, посмотрел код, так и не понял чего хотите. Вот как из `Tom4` получается `Project aaaa`, да еще который и прибит гвоздями в коде. `Нужно чтобы в (3) было префикс + имя.` - Как вы его привязали? Вот также и передавайте, у вас ведь есть все нужные свойства, берите из них что хотите и генерируйте как надо то, что надо... Ну а вообще, вы делаете уйму лишнего, и яб сказал даже нарушающее MVVM. Например, зачем вам везде INPC, если его можно вынести в отдельный класс и наследовать? Зачем `Convert.ToInt32(NumberStart)`, когда сразу можно сделать нужный тип? И т.д.

Comment: В WPF лучше использовать `ObservableCollection`, а не `BindingList`.

Comment: сейчас в (3) показаны исходные( старые) имена (Project aaa, Project bbbb, ... )
т.е. в (3) нужно:
Tom4Project aaa
Tom5Project bbbb
....

Comment: насколько я понимаю  ObservableCollection оповещает только если в коллекцию добавляется, либо что то удаляется, а BindingList об изменении в коллекции ... потому и стал пытаться с ним

Comment: Этот список потом куда либо идет? И зачем вам вообще все эти классы, вся ваша задача решается несколькими строками кода.

Comment: Этот список потом куда либо идет? 
- да, пойдет. (переименовка будет)
И зачем вам вообще все эти классы, вся ваша задача решается несколькими строками кода
- у меня небольшой опыт, делал взяв за основу  MVVM с метанита. возможно я не прав
а вопрос класс InputTextNumber в основном вызывает?

Comment: Решение всей вашей задачи сводится к чему-то вроде [такого](https://pastebin.com/9AumrWLx), ну а XAML будет, например, [таким](https://pastebin.com/JtAuGGVb), результат будет [таким](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGVkU.png). Чтоб это соответствовало MVVM, `Names` и `UpdateResults` должны быть в Model слое, а все остальное в ViewModel, то есть просто делим тоже самое на 2-3 класса. Все остальное это уже незначительные аспекты (имена например вывести также в UI можно). Ну а теперь гляньте на свой код, где вы делаете тонну непонятных действий, спрашивается - зачем? Для чего?

Comment: EvgeniyZ - спасибо что отвечаете! и в вашем ответе я нашел для себя новые примеры! 
во первых я похоже сильно упростил вопрос - потому для понимания добавил xaml
во вторых я упомянул, что мне не только префиксы нужны, но и суффиксы (а потом походу и найти и заменить). Т.е. класс InputTextNumber для того чтобы :
а) не создавать свойства Text и StartNumber для префикса , суффикса и т.п.
б) использовать в ItemsControl

Comment: Я не отвечаю, я лишь с вами общаюсь, пытаясь понять задачу что у меня пока не особо выходит. `мне не только префиксы нужны, но и суффиксы` - что в вашем понимании "суффикс"? `не создавать свойства Text и StartNumber для префикса , суффикса и т.п.` - ну ок, это два свойства, которые вы выносите в отдельный класс, ок (правда не пойму, зачем суффиксу стартовый номер тогда), но зачем нужен генерированный лист суффиксов, если он дальше, как я понял не выводится, а в вопросе вы вывили его чисто для наглядности, почему просто не генерировать сразу нужную строку? Я вам дал пример, что в нем не так?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ - в примере все так, если бы я использовал все свойства в VM и не выносил в отдельный класс InputTextNumber .  У меня не понимание как сгенерированный список в другой класс перекинуть с отслеживанием изменений(((
Вопросом -  не пойму, зачем суффиксу стартовый номер тогда - Вы меня направили на дополнительное применение моей задачи!)) но т.к. в комментарии не добавить скрин то сейчас добавлю UPD3

Comment: `я использовал все свойства в VM` - ну так я вам сказал вроде, что мой пример без проблем разбивается на отдельные классы, где имена, и генерирование данных должно быть в Model слое (классе), а все остальное в VM слое, где на основе все той-же логики будет лишь вызываться метод не самой VM, а уже модели, условно не `UpdateResults()`, а `var newData = model.Generate(); Result.AddRange(newData);`. `в другой класс перекинуть` - я не пойму зачем вам список сгенерированных префиксов, ну да ладно. А перекинуть - он у вас и так уже в VM, и вы даже делаете `InputPrefix.ResultList.ListChanged +=`...

Comment: Ну вот самая базовая передача данных как делается в C#? Конструктор, свойство, аргументы метода, события. То есть `new SomeClass(mySuperItem)`/`someClass.SomeMethod(mySuperItem)`/`someClass.MySuperItem = mySuperItem`/`someClass.Event+=(s, e) => { var someItem = e.SomeItem; }`. Вы вон подписались на событие, передали тем самым данные (если надо), также у вас есть доступ к этим данным через простые свойства. Ну и как бы, я не совсем понимаю о какой передаче идет речь. Тыкните прям носом что и где у вас должно появиться, и почему вы это сейчас не можете сделать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  не понимаю как из InputPrefix .ResultList в Prefixes (( 
т.е. я не понимаю как в AppViewModel отследить изменения в  InputPrefix .ResultList

Comment: У вас `ListChanged` вызывается вообще? Я так понимаю, что нет.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот в коде InputPrefixListChanged ... но наверное неправильно вызывается - не понимаю как вызвать из другого класса

Comment: Вопрос не где он, а вызывается-ли он? Выполняется метод `InputPrefixListChanged`? Я просто вижу, что вы у `ResultList` переопределили `get`, в котором постоянно создаете **новую** коллекцию, со своим набором данных. Условно вы делаете так `var items = new BindingList<..>(); items.ListChanged += ...; items = new BindingList<...>();`. Каждое обращение к этому свойству == создание новой коллекции. При написании `var items = InputPrefix.ResultList;` или даже `{Binding InputPrefix.ResultList}` у вас должна возвращаться всегда одна коллекция (если не задумано иначе).